# Adding values in a existing csv file

Tags: python, csv

```
import os
import csv
import time
import stat
import pandas as pd


def update_csv_file():

    dir_path = "V:/Database/results"
    csv_file_path = "C:/Temp/csv/table_all_results_meta.csv"

    csv = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
        for di in dirs:
            print(di)
            name = di
            path = dir_path + '/' + di
            print("path: ", path)
            db = name.split('_')[2]
            print("Dataset: ", db)
            date_time = os.stat(path)
            creation_time = time.ctime(date_time[stat.ST_CTIME])
            print("Creation time: ", creation_time)
            version = name.split('result_files_' + db + '_')[1]
            print("version: ", version)

            csv.loc[:, 'DataTime'] = creation_time
            csv.loc[:, 'Dataset'] = db
            csv.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    update_csv_file()
```

[image: existing csv file]

I want to add the value from the code (e.g. version in the version column in the csv) in a new row for every folders in the dir.

Currently it's not working as expected with this code!

Comment: "it's not working as expected": Can you be more specific?

Comment: DataTime Dataset Path Version     
V:/Database/database/results V:/Database/database/results  V:/Database/database/results  V:/Database/database/results       
db db db db                                                                                                                                        **It's adding the value like this in the csv**